# Mysql Multiple AND inner join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to return all flights between with the departure date greater or equal to a certain date e.g 2016-12-09 and less than or equal 2016-12-11

I want to include all departure airports which which have 'London' in the airport name and all arrival airports which have 'Charles' or 'Orly' in the airport name. When I run this query I don't get any results.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `OR` between the arrival airport checks, not `AND`.

```
WHERE departure.airport_name_en LIKE '%London%' 
AND (arrival.airport_name_en LIKE '%Charles%' 
    OR arrival.airport_name_en LIKE '%Orly%')
AND departure_date BETWEEN '2016-12-09' AND '2016-12-11'
```

`AND` requires *both* conditions to be true, but unless the airport name is something like `Charles de Orly International`, it won't have both `Charles` and `Orly` in it. You even said it correctly in the question:

> arrival airports which have 'Charles' **or** 'Orly' in the airport name

Make sure you use parentheses when you mix `AND` and `OR` conditions, because the precedence isn't what you likely expect.